# Mosh installed but not seen as such

Tags: ubuntu, mosh

The following steam of error messages are being generated when trying to connect to a server via `mosh`.  This is notwithstanding the fact that the command was previously run and showed mosh was already installed on the server.

```
sudo apt-get install mosh
[sudo] password for jerdvo:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mosh is already the newest version (1.3.2-2.1build3).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfwupdplugin1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 46 not upgraded.
```

The errors are as follows.  There is an indication of inappropriate locales in addition to `Did not find mosh server startup message`

Which rabbit should I pursue first and how?

server: ubuntu 20.04
local: OSX 10.13.6

```
The locale requested by LC_CTYPE=UTF-8 isn't available here.
Running `locale-gen UTF-8' may be necessary.

The locale requested by LC_CTYPE=UTF-8 isn't available here.
Running `locale-gen UTF-8' may be necessary.

mosh-server needs a UTF-8 native locale to run.

Unfortunately, the local environment (LC_CTYPE=UTF-8) specifies
the character set "US-ASCII",

The client-supplied environment (LC_CTYPE=UTF-8) specifies
the character set "US-ASCII".

locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
Connection to 159...33 closed.
/usr/local/bin/mosh: Did not find mosh server startup message. (Have you installed mosh on your server?)
```

I've tried this, as suggested in the comments:

```
locale-gen UTF-8
Error: 'UTF-8' is not a supported language or locale
```

... which I do find odd...

Then ran

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
en_us.UTF-8

sudo update-locale 
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
Error: 'UTF-8' is not a supported language or locale
```

Where now?

Comment: `Error: 'UTF-8' is not a supported language or locale` ... which I do find odd...

Comment: Then ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` chose en_us.UTF-8 followed by `sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8`.  Same result as above.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to comment the `SendEnv` from macOS's `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

```
Host *
    SendEnv LANG LC_*  # comment this line
```